# calling UITableView reload function before another function

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

```
-(void)didTapAudioButton:(UIButton*)sender {
   [tableView reloadData];
   UIButton* senderButton = (UIButton*)sender;
   NSUInteger index = sender.tag;
   NSString *audioFilePath = @"someAudioFilePath.mp3";// I didn't add the original audiofile path for security reasons
   NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:audioFilePath]];
   NSError *error;
   audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_objectData error:&error];
   audioPlayer.delegate = self;
   audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
    if (audioPlayer == nil)
       {
           NSLog([error description]);
       }
       else
       {
           [audioPlayer play];
       }
  }
```

I am using this function to play Audio File on button click from a URL String Path. The audio is playing fine but the issue is that [tableView reloadData] function is being called at the end of this function. I want the tableView to reload fist and then go to the next line i.e, 
UIButton* senderButton = (UIButton*)sender;
Can anybody tell me how to reload tableview before playing audio? Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you can this method in main thread?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question. This function is called when I clicked on a button inside a view. See the first line of function. I am calling tableview reloadData to reload tableView whenever I clicked the button and I want to do it before playing audio file. But when I clicked the button, first it goes through the whole function and then at the end it calls the tableView reloadData. Hope you understand my question :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the following line:

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
```

It will wait until the method is done.

Comment: Its not working. Actually the issue is that it won't call delegate functions of UITableView on reload data at first. I am using breakpoints to check this functionality. When I clicked the button first it goes through all the code of this button event and then at the end it calls cellForRowAtIndex and other delegate functions of UITableView.

Comment: The button that plays the audio file is inside a UITableViewCell. I am using this line of code for calling its event when clicked.  [((QuestionReplyCell *) cell).btnQuestionVoice addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapAudioButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: So when the button is clicked, I want to reload this tableView first and then play the audioFile. I have a list of questions in tableview each having an audio button to play that questions audio file. I am also changing the image of button when the audio is playing. That's why I want to reload tableview first and then change the image of selected button. Hope you understand what I am trying to do. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Have you tried adding [self.tableview layoutIfNeeded]; after the reloadData call?

Comment: No I did not. After adding this line of code its working fine. Thanks a lot bro.. You are the man.. :)

Comment: No problem. I added the line in the answer above. :)